# Getting the storageId from Url

Tags: aframe, archilogic, 3d.io

Does someone know from a 3d model how to get the `storageID`? There seems to be a method like this, but it keeps telling me invalid url. thanks !

```
io3d.storage.getIdFromUrl('https://spaces.archilogic.com/3d/Home_2766/grrodvuu?modelResourceId=cd36dc78-a124-4a4e-9990-35be32415f84')
```

Comment: You're getting the error because the `io3d.storage.getIdFromUrl` only works for storage URLs (such as this example: https://3d.io/docs/api/1/storage.html#url) , not for model URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are looking for the storage ID of the entire baked model?

In that case, you can use the Scene API to find the child with the `bakedModelUrl` which is the storage ID of the model:

```
// this is the modelResourceId from the URL you gave in your question
io3d.scene.getStructure('cd36dc78-a124-4a4e-9990-35be32415f84')
  // we select the children
  .then(scene => scene.children)
  // find the child that has a bakedModelUrl
  .then(children => children.find(child => child.bakedModelUrl))
  // read the bakedModelUrl
  .then(level => level.bakedModelUrl)
  // and log it (or do whatever you need to do with it)
  .then(console.log)
```